# How to Dynamically Import Modules in Python with Nested Directories and `__init__.py` Files?

Tags: python, file, import, python-import, pyproject.toml

I'm working on a Python project with a complex directory structure that includes nested directories, and I've added `__init__.py` files to each of these directories. My goal is to dynamically import modules from these directories without having to specify the full path to the module in my import statements.

For instance, I'd like to avoid this kind of import statement:

```py
from src.function.function import get_service
```

Instead, I'd prefer a more concise approach like this:

```py
from function import get_service
```

Here's the directory structure for my project:

```
my_project/
|-- src/
|   |-- __init__.py
|   |-- function/
|   |   |-- __init__.py
|   |   |-- token.txt
|   |   |-- service.py
|   |   |-- function.py
|-- tests/
|   |-- __init__.py
|   |-- test_test_function.py
```

I'm looking for a way to achieve this dynamic module import behavior. Do I need to set up anything specific in my `__init__.py` files or use a custom import mechanism? Also, if there is a `pyproject.toml` file or any other configuration options that can be used to control which modules are included in the dynamic imports, please let me know.

Comment: This should be trivial using any build system. Pick one, setup `pyproject.toml` with whatever top-levels packages/modules you want, done. Just do note that any given module will only ever be at a single package location. So if you make `function.py` a top-level module, it won't be possible to, for example, import `service.py` using a relative import.

Comment: In terms of design, it's probably not the best idea to make your project contains tons of _top-level_ modules. A single top-level package with submodules is usually much more manageable. ([namespaces are one honking great idea](https://peps.python.org/pep-0020/) after all.) If you want to make imports more concise, you can always using relative imports (e.g. `from .functions import get_service` in `service.py`).